# Ionic templates folder not show anything

Tags: ionic-framework

I've started to learn ionic framework recently. I created below files, but result is blank page. nothing shows in the developer tools in Google Chrome too.

**app.js**

```
var app = angular.module('sheikhsafi', ['ionic']);

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
       url: '/',
       views: {
          home: {
          templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
       }
     }
  })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')
});

app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope, $stateParams) {

})
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
   <title></title>
   <link href="lib/ionic/css/ionic.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
   <script src="cordova.js"></script>
   <script src="js/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="sheikhsafi">
   <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
</body>
</html>
```

**templates/home.html**

```
<script id="templates/home.html" type="text/ng-template">
   <ion-view title="Home">
      <ion-content>
         <ion-pane>Hi</ion-pane>
      </ion-content>
   </ion-view>
<script>
```

what's the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[**Working plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/KDfqXSzLCgXYUJyJfkjk?p=preview).

Wrong code in `config` section of **app.js**. The correct is:

```
.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider

    .state('app', {
       url: '/',
       templateUrl: 'templates/home.html'
      });

  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')
})
```

instead of your:

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider
    .state('index', {
       url: '/',
       views: {
          home: {
            templateUrl: 'templates/home.html',
          }
       }
    })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/')
});
```

In your case you're trying to add to `home` view a template, that has sense when you have an abstract view. Take a look to the [ionic-starter-sidemenu](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-starter-sidemenu), that could be a nice way to discover some things.

Also, if you're learning ionic, please read the [getting started guide](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/), and use one of them ready-made app templates.

Comment: thank you for answer, but not works. still shows nothing.